# Problem by rasterizing in QGIS 3.28.4: resulting raster is only white

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization

I have a shapefile with one polygon (trajectory of a rockfall). The last column contains the max altitude of the polygon (calculated with the function Zonal Statistics). I want to use the raster calculator to do further calculations, meaning that I need to rasterize this vector layer.

But somehow when I run the tool I get weird data and the resulting raster is only white.

Do you know what might be the problem?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows that you created a raster with the resolution 1 pixel widht, 1 pixel height. Adapt resolution and units to get proper results. See also [rasterize documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster).

[image]